# line breaks not working after <br/> tag

Tags: html, css

Below is my code:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px"><img src="06fc499c-5329-419c-b0df-644ee5d8439b_icon48.png"></div>

<br/>

<div>&nbsp;<strong>1</strong>&nbsp;<a href="1">2</a>&nbsp;<a href="2">&gt;</a>&nbsp;</div>
```

I found that style="float: left; margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px" that causes all on the same line, when i remove the `style="float: left; margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px"`, 
The line break  after `<br/>` tag operates normally. However, I wanted to keep ` style="float: left; margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px" from the beginning. How do I use the line break in this case?

Thanks so much for advice.`

Comment: Why do you want to use `float` if you don't want the content that follows it to be beside it?

Comment: You are setting `float:left` to that first div, this floats the block element `<br/>` on the right of the div. That won't work. You could tell us graphically what you are trying to achieve and we'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding `style="clear: both"` which makes the element drop below any floated elements that precede it in the document.